# Yet another play store df-dferh-01 issue, Pixel 3a

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account, google-play-services

Pixel 3a here.

After a fresh install of the latest factory image, I was unable to download apps from play store.

Searching or browsing apps in the store are without any problem, but once I tapped Install button it shows  `Error retrieving information from server [DF-DFERH-01]` like other people.

I've tried to clean the cache/storage, uninstall update, re-login Google account, countless reboot between the methods above, but none worked.

One thing I've noticed is that those apps have been installed before, are able to be installed again, and those dont are not.

So I suspect it's a problem related to my account, or their server, any clue helps, thanks.